# PayPal IPN recommended file permissions

Tags: php, paypal-ipn

I'm wondering what is the recommended file permission for my ipn.php file. I haven't read anything about file permissions regarding PayPal IPN. For the meantime, I set mine as 0755.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's on your own server that's fine. If on a shared server, and you are able to chgrp it to the webserver group (www-data on Debian, usually), you could make it 750. If you're using suexec, you might be able to make it 700.

Comment: Thank you for your brief explanation Sir!